# How to make a year range column into separate columns?

Tags: python

I am using Python to analyze a data set that has a column with a year range (see below for example):

| Name | Years Range |
| --- | --- |
| Andy | 1985 - 1987 |
| Bruce | 2011 - 2018 |

I am trying to convert the "Years Range" column that has a string of start and end years into two separate columns within the data frame to: "Year Start" and "Year End".

| Name | Years Range | Year Start | Year End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | 1985 - 1987 | 1985 | 1987 |
| Bruce | 2011 - 2018 | 2011 | 2018 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expand=True within `split` function

```
df[['Year Start','Year End']]  = df['Years Range'].str.split('-',expand=True)
```

output #

```
    Nmae Years_Range Year Start Year End
0   NAdy   1995-1987       1995     1987
1  bruce   1890-8775       1890     8775
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `str.extract` can do the job.

Here is an example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ "1985 - 1987"], columns = [ "Years Range"])

df['Year Start'] = df['Years Range'].str.extract('(\d{4})')
df['Year End'] = df['Years Range'].str.extract('- (\d{4})')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['start']=''#create a blank column name 'start'
df['end']=''#create a blank column name 'end'
#loop over the data frame
for i in range(len(df)):
  df['start'][i]=df['Year'][i].split('-')[0]#split each data and store first element
  df['end'][i]=df['Year'][i].split('-')[1]#split each data and store second element
```

[https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Kemzk-aSUKRfE_eSrsQ7jS6e0NwhbXWp#scrollTo=esXNvRpnSN9I&line=1&uniqifier=1](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Kemzk-aSUKRfE_eSrsQ7jS6e0NwhbXWp#scrollTo=V68o-I63WOkU&uniqifier=1)